# How to get column names and values from a single-row resultset with PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, resultset, associative

I need to get all column names and values in the row where `id` = `$id`.

Column names should be echoed as `title`; values should be echoed as `story`

Something like this:

```
function story($id) {
    global $db;
    $sql = "select *  from users where id = :aid limit 1";
    $st = $db->prepare($sql);
    $st -> execute([":aid" => $id]);
    $row = $st->fetch();
    $sql = // select all column names;
    $columns = // array - result of $sql
    $story = "";
    foreach ($columns as $el) {
        $i = array_search($el, $columns);
        $val = $row[$i];
        $story .=
        "<div class='title'>" . $el . "</div>\n" .
        "<div class='story'>" . $val . "</div>\n";
    }
    echo $story;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `array_search()`?  Build the resultset that you want to work with.  I recommend passing `$db` as a function parameter instead of declaring `global`.

Comment: @mickmackusa, because I need that index to get appropriate element in `row` array;

Comment: `->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`?

Comment: @mickmackusa, sorry, can't understand, where should I write that?

Comment: If you just do: `$row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`, you will get the row as an associative array. No need for anything else. [Here's the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: I feel like you table design may be "questionable" if you are using column names as part of your output.  What kind of schema are we looking at here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to do `array_search()`, do like below:-

```
function story($id) {
    global $db;
    $sql = "select *  from users where id = :aid limit 1";
    $st = $db->prepare($sql);
    $st -> execute([":aid" => $id]);
    $row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(count($row)>=1){
      foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
        echo "<div class='title'>" . $column . "</div>\n" .
        echo "<div class='story'>" . $value. "</div>\n";
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you pass the db connection as a function parameter instead of using a `global` declaration.

`fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` returns a one-dimensional associative array or `false`.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Using capitalization on your sql keywords can improve readability.

I have removed the LIMIT clause, but if your `id` column is the PRIMARY KEY, the limit won't matter.

```
function story($db, $id) {
    $st = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :aid");
    $st->execute([":aid" => $id]);
    if (!$row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "no row found";
    }
    foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
        echo "<div class='title'>" . $key . "</div>\n";
        echo "<div class='story'>" . $val . "</div>\n";
    }
}
```

I do have a suspicion that your database table design may not be optimal.  Typically you'll want a stable column structure that allows your row count to increase.  If your table is expanding both vertically and horizontally, I wonder what your requirements are.

Comment: what is the difference ?

Comment: `global` scoped variables are not recommended versus passing the connection as a parameter into the custom function.  Also, the `count()` on the row is not necessary.  If `id` is a primary/unique key (and it usually is in properly designed tables), then `LIMIT 1` is not necessary.

Answer (score -2):

You're approaching it a bit wrong...
When a $sql returns with mysqli as an associative array, it returns the column name as the key...

hence:

```
$columns = // array - result of $sql as an assoc array
$story = "";
foreach ($columns as $key => value) {
    $story .=
    "<div class='title'>" . $key . "</div>\n" .
    "<div class='story'>" . $value . "</div>\n";
}
```